# How to improve this dialog

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have this simple dialog which will be called when application is closed.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class test extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {

        // Image
        Image image = new Image("http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/"
                + "javafx/images/javafx-documentation.png");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(image);

        // Text
        Text t = new Text();
        t.setText("This is a text sample");

        // Buttons
        Button btnYes = new Button("Yes");
        Button btnNo = new Button("No");

        // Buttons layout
        HBox hbox = new HBox(8); // spacing = 8
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-padding: 15; -fx-font-size: 15pt;");
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(btnYes, btnNo);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT);

        ////////////////////////

        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setPadding(new Insets(10, 20, 10, 20));
        //Button btnTop = new Button("Top");
        bp.setTop(null);
        //Button btnLeft = new Button("Left");
        bp.setLeft(imageView);
        //Button btnCenter = new Button("Center");
        bp.setCenter(t);
        //Button btnRight = new Button("Right");
        bp.setRight(null);
        //Button btnBottom = new Button("Bottom");
        bp.setBottom(hbox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 500, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

so far it looks like this:

[image]

I want to make it to look like this:

[image]

Can you help me how to improve the visual layout of the button? I don't know how to make this buttons to look like the example and how to set the background color gradient.

Comment: Use SceneBuilder. See [Styling FX Buttons with CSS](http://fxexperience.com/2011/12/styling-fx-buttons-with-css/).

Comment: You have copied the image from ControlsFX so, since it is open source just copy the code as well.

Answer (score 2):

The second dialog shows the `Modena` JavaFX style, that will be default in `Java 8` and can be enabled in prior Java 8 builds like shown [here](http://fxexperience.com/2013/01/modena-new-theme-for-javafx-8).

```
setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_MODENA);
```

Comment: Also the second dialog comes from the **[ControlsFX](https://bitbucket.org/JonathanGiles/controlsfx)** open source project and can be freely used. There is no sense to reinvent the wheel :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [MonologFX](https://blogs.oracle.com/javajungle/entry/monologfx_floss_javafx_dialogs_for)? It is part of the [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org/) package. It will give you most of what you want and you can style the buttons as described [here](http://clarkonium.net/2013/05/styled-dialogs-in-javafx-with-jfxtras-monologfx/).